# Lazy loading function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In our code sometimes we need a function to load after some time the page is loaded, for stuff like caching the articles of website which is not needed while the page load is happening.

I was wondering if we can write or use some syntax which can **lazy** load that particular function.

Example:

```js
lazyload funnction xyz(){
    // put your code here
}
```

If there is any way to do this or something similar approach, It is fine if you point me to any patterns, frameworks etc.

Comment: You can load a _file_ later on. Not a particular function _inside this file_.

Comment: [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: You can hold the execution of the function until DOM is ready and loaded.

Comment: Think of this way, how does the web browser know if this function is `lazyload` before the file is downloaded? But you can add `async` or `defer` to the `script` tag to make it loads asynchronously though.

Comment: Are you using Vanilla JS? Or Node? We need more info on the actual architecture you're using... But if you're looking to like create your own syntactical sugar to add to a function, you're biting off more than you can chew.  Better to look into JS modules and architectural patterns setup to support lazy loading.

Comment: https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: I am using basic javascript, that too not es6 or es5 so need to check if I can use *async* in my code since I have to support IE as well.

Comment: there are little reason to lazy load a function, however you can simply lazy *call* the function like @ AnandG said.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should distinguish between "lazy loading" and "delayed loading".

- Lazy loading very specifically means loading when it's necessary. In this case, it means try running some code, if not loaded, then load and run. This would imply that load will be immediately followed by run.
- Delayed loading means loading at an arbitrarily-decided time for any reason, without necessarily running the code immediately. In other words, delayed loading is a superset of lazy loading.

---

I'm not sure whether your need is strictly lazy loading. But their implementation is similar enough. This is how I would do it, assuming you don't want to use modules.

Idea: have the lazily-loaded code in a separate file, and load the file by adding a `script` tag to your DOM. Then set an arbitrary trigger for this action to achieve delayed loading.

#### In `main.js`:

```
function loadDelayed() {
  const tag = "<script src='delayed.js'></script>";
  document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tag);
}
// E.g. trigger via timeout after 5 seconds
setTimeout(loadDelayed, 5000);
```

#### In `delayed.js`:

```
function myDelayedFunc() {
  // Your code here
}
```

---

If you just want lazy loading, create one `.js` file for each lazily-loaded function:

E.g. `func1.js`:

```
(() => {
  // Your code here
})();
```

And in `main.js` create a helper function:

```
function runLazy(funcName) {
  const tag = `<script src='${funcName}.js'></script>`;
  document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tag);
}

runLazy("func1");
```

Note: although the browser will load the file from cache after the first call, this naive approach will always add a new script tag to your DOM every time you call `runLazy()`. If you intend to call the function many times, you might wish to use `loadDelayed()` and then call the function normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script dynamically using JavaScript:

```js
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "/caching.js";
document.body.append(script);
```

The script will start loading once it's been added to the document.

Dynamically loaded scripts behave like `async` by default, but you can change the order from “First Loaded – First Executed” to the order in which they are appended into the document by explicitly setting the `async` property to `false`:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "caching.js";

script.async = false;

document.body.append(script);
```